# How do you make text appear under a div without affecting the div

Tags: html, css

Im trying to on hover make text appear under these circles but when ever I try to add paragraphs they just make my circles go out of place.

This is what I'm trying to achieve
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSl9k.jpg

https://jsfiddle.net/u02e1mfe/

HTML

```
<div class="row">
        <p><b>Works</b></p>
        <div "row1">
            <div class="round-button">
                <div class="round-button-circle" class=".col-md-4">
                    <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank" class="round-button">Google</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="round-button">
                <div class="round-button-circle" class=".col-md-4">
                    <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank" class="round-button">nn</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="round-button">
                <div class="round-button-circle" class=".col-md-4">
                    <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank" class="round-button">nm</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div "row2">
            <div class="round-button">
                <div class="round-button-circle" class=".col-md-4">
                    <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank" class="round-button">nn</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="round-button">
                <div class="round-button-circle" class=".col-md-4">
                    <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank" class="round-button">nff</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="round-button">
```

CSS

```
.row
{
    height: 80%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top: 2%;
    font-size: 25;
}
.round-button {
    display:inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width:10%;
    padding-top: 2%;
}
.round-button-circle {
    height: 100px;
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
    border:2px solid #f0f0f0;
    background: white no-repeat center center;
    -moz-border-radius:100px;
    -webkit-border-radius:100px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    cursor:pointer;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
    font-size: 0%;
}
.round-button-circle:hover {
    background:#000000;
    text-decoration-color: white;
    font-size: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 80%;
}
.round-button a{
    display:block;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    padding-top:50%;
    padding-bottom:50%;
    line-height:1em;
    margin-top:-0.5em;

    text-align:center;
    color:#e2eaf3;
    font-family:Verdana;
    font-size:1.2em;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

They are close together in the fiddle but in my actual website they aren't like that so just ignore it. Im trying to make the text appear below the circle when you hover over it. Any ideas? New to CSS and HTML

Comment: `<div "row1">` is what markup?

Comment: Could it be the `margin-bottom: 80%;` you've added on the hover state?

Comment: No I'm trying to add text to where the margin is. Moving it with margin probably isn't the best idea but I just wanted to demonstrate it. Where the margin is is where I would like the text to go. Adding a paragraph and making it only visible on hover still changes the layout of the circles so I can't do that

Comment: Have a look at this updated fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/u02e1mfe/1/

Comment: What does that change though? The regular style looks fine for me but I'm trying to make it so when you hover over it it'll display text under the button. Its for a portfolio project I'm building in school. This is what i'm trying to achieve. http://imgur.com/jycg0ic

Comment: http://imgur.com/TZfpQIF Wrong imgur.

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines to `.round-button a` css

```
position: absolute;
bottom: -90px;
color: red;
```

(You can replace the color, is just for you to notice the change)